# single submit button for a form which has two or three hiding divs

Tags: jquery

how to have a single submit button for a form which has two or three hiding divs using jquery,can any one provide me a live example of it.

thanks in advance.
-Ashwan

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958907/only-visible-div-form-elements-will-get-submitted

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jquery submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

It is basically along the lines of

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a fiddle, just look at here http://jsfiddle.net/8nhmU/17/

**Source :**

```
<form id="frmDemo">
 <div id="div0">Hi</div>

<div id="div1">Hello</div>

<div id="div2">Hi</div>

<input type="button" value="submit" id="btnsumbit"/>
</form>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnsumbit").click(function(){
        $("#div0,#div1,#div2").css('display','none');
    });
});
```